# Как обработать кириллический буквенно-цифровой символ регулярным выражением?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, replace

Обрабатываю строку с помощью конструкции:

`this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\w]/ig, '');`

Заметил, что кириллические символы не воспринимаются как буквенные в JavaScript, что отличается от поведения `\w`, например, для `preg_replace` в `php`.

Кодировка страницы UTF-8.

Решение `А-я` работает, но его недостаток - (предположительно) необходимость под каждый алфавит, отличный от латиницы, прописывать соответствующий диапазон.

Прошу подсказать, есть ли возможность в `js` отследить буквенные символы в кириллице без конструкции вида `А-я`? Существует ли универсальное решение?

Comment: \w - у этой штуки есть проблемы с кирилицей, она хорошо работает с латинецей.

Comment: @IhorBondartcov нет у этой штуки никаких проблем с кириллицей, ибо она соответствует `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: @teran Вот ты правильно все написал - она соответствует латинеце и цифрам но не кирилеце

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Современные регулярные выражения в JavaScript в большинстве своём поддерживают стандарт ECMAScript 2018, который сделал возможным использование блоков просмотра назад, именных подмасок, флага `s`, а главное, символьные классы Юникода.

```js
const str = "Пора поговорить с ним tête-à-tête.";
const regex = /\P{L}/gu;  // определение регулярного выражения
//var regex = /[^\p{L}\s]/gu; // => Пора поговорить с ним têteàtête (если надо оставить пробелы или добавить исключения)
const result = str.replace(regex, '');
console.log(result);
// => Порапоговоритьснимtêteàtête
```

Не забывайте использовать флаг `u`, и тогда вы сможете использовать любые символьные классы Юникода, например, кириллический `\p{Script=Cyrl}`:

```js
const text = '"True" — это "ЛОЖЬ".';
console.log(text.replace(/\p{Script=Cyrl}+/gu, '')); // => "True" —  "".
console.log(text.replace(/\P{Script=Cyrl}+/gu, ' ').trim()); // это ЛОЖЬ
```

**Прошлый ответ**

Используйте [библитеку XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode), в которой осуществлена поддержка категорий Юникода в регулярных выражениях. Чтобы найти все символы, являющиеся буквами любого алфавита, нужно использовать `\pL`/`\p{L}`, а чтобы найти все остальные символы, используйте `\PL`/`\p{^L}`.

```js
var str = "Пора поговорить с ним tête-à-tête.";
var regex = new XRegExp('\\PL');  // определение регулярного выражения
//var regex = new XRegExp('[^\\pL\\s]'); // => Пора поговорить с ним têteàtête (если надо оставить пробелы или добавить исключения)
var result = XRegExp.replace(str, regex, '', 'all'); // 'all' - заменить все вхождения
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.1.1/xregexp-all.min.js"></script>
```